# $_GET stopped working for deleting records

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, get

For a webapplication I'm building the delete user function stopped working. I didn't change anything related to this function. So I'm quite puzzeled.
I have PHP Console installed in chrome (and the app). But it isn't giving any errors or warnings.

I'm using bootbox to verify if the user really should be deleted:

```
function delete_id(id, fullname) {
    bootbox.confirm({
        size: 'small',
        message: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign orange"></i>Are you sure you want to delete user "'+fullname+'"?',
        callback: function(result) {
            if(result) {
                window.location.href = '?delete_id='+id;
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Then it should be passed through my php function:

```
function delete_user ($mysqli) {
    if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
        $sql_name = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='".$_GET['delete_id']."'";
        $result_name = $mysqli->query($sql_name);
        $row = $result_name->fetch_assoc();

        $sql_log = "DELETE FROM loginlog WHERE uid='".$row['uid']."'";
        $result_log = $mysqli->query($sql_log);

        $sql_user = "DELETE FROM users WHERE uid='".$row['uid']."'";
        $result_user = $mysqli->query($sql_user) or die(mysqli_errno($mysqli));

        $_SESSION['success'] = "User \"".$row['firstname']." ".$row['prefix']." ".$row['lastname']."\" is deleted.";
        header("location: ".BASE_PATH."/includes/views/users.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

the `delete_user()` function is called in `users.php`
 And this was working just fine, but now it isn't anymore.. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and vulnerable to the [Spider of Doom](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom). Enjoy having your site destroyed.

Comment: How does it "not work"?  Where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: sql injection seems unlikely, because it is an intranet application. Spider of doom seems to need pages that delete the record (not a javascript triggered function) and robots aren't allowed as per robots.txt. Or wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: The '?delete_id=n is added to the url, but the php function is not doing anything after that.

Comment: The function takes a mysqli object. Have you verified that it is connecting successfully?

Comment: Yes other functions using the same object do work.

Comment: Where is called `delete_user()`...?

Comment: inside the users.php file

Comment: Is `$_GET['delete_id']` still getting populated? Your first `if` statement would prevent it from doing anything. I would advise adding in `else { return false }`. That way you can check if it ran or not.

Comment: @MartijnICU: and if a browser decides to start pre-fetching pages? just because a search engine spider can't get in, don't assume that NOTHING can get in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise:

```
function delete_user ($mysqli, $id) {
    if(isset($id)) {
        $sql_name = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='%d'", $id);
        $result_name = $mysqli->query($sql_name);
        $row = $result_name->fetch_assoc();

        $sql_log = "DELETE FROM loginlog WHERE uid='{$row['uid']}'";
        $result_log = $mysqli->query($sql_log);

        $sql_user = "DELETE FROM users WHERE uid='{$row['uid']}'";
        $result_user = $mysqli->query($sql_user) or die(mysqli_errno($mysqli));

        $_SESSION['success'] = "User \"{$row['firstname']} {$row['prefix']} {$row['lastname']}\" is deleted.";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can execute:

```
if(delete_user($sql, $_GET['id'])){
    header("location: ".BASE_PATH."/includes/views/users.php");
}
```

It's always good to use best practices, even in a intranet. One rouge user or someone that thinks they know a little something, and you could lose tables or have rows fowled. ALWAYS protect your user entered data, especially from the users.